# Printing out elements from tables in a database, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite

I'm currently trying and failing to learn Ruby on Rails. I've been tasked with the job of printing our different elements in different tables from a database in a lovely table look.
So I'm guessing thats not explained very well, so I have 3 table in the database `Person`, `score` and `quiz` so I need to print out the `name, age, height` from the `person` table and the `averageScore` from the `score` table and `quizId` from the `quiz` table.

Currently I have this page in the `views/pages/databaseshow` folder. Is this the correct place to have it?

the code I have so far is probably completely wrong but here it is anyway.

```
%tr
        %td= person.forename
        %td= person.surname
        %td= person.height
        %td= score.averageScore
        %td= quiz.quizId
```

The score table is linked to the person table via id numbers.

I'm sorry if this is vague but I sort of having a stab in the dark on how to even go about doing it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your code will be like this

```
%tr
    %td= person.forename
    %td= person.surname
    %td= person.height
    %td= person.score.averageScore
    %td= person.quiz.quizId
```

Comment: @neo-streets..Also supply more info if you require more accurate answer

Comment: What else should i add

Answer (score 0):

@Anil Kumar 's code is most probably correct.

Answer to your comment: What info to add to get accurate answers:

- Try to include the model relationships (`belongs_to`, `has_many`, `has_one`, etc.) so we can visualize the schema easily and answer better.

> Currently I have this page in the `views/pages/databaseshow` folder. Is this the correct place to have it?

Yes this shouldnt be a problem, just know,
in Rails, most of the time: `views/pages/databaseshow` means that you are rendering:

```
controller: pages  
action: databaseshow
```

So you should have the `PagesController` with the action `databaseshow` defined.